# Insert statement for a Service with Spring Jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm working on a Restful's Service project and I'm trying to persist a entity thorugh a service but I don't know how to write the params that reference to another objects ... Here is some code of my classes.

**Domain Classes**

```
@Component
@Entity 
public class Atleta extends Persona implements java.io.Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private Skill skill

    private Result result


}
```

---

```
@Entity 
public class Skill implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private string description

    public Skill() {
    }

    public Skill(Atleta atleta, String description) {
        super();
        this.atleta = atleta;
        this.description = description;

    }

    //..Getters and Setters
```

**Dao Interfaces**

```
public interface DaoAtletaI extends JpaRepository<Atleta, Integer> {

}
```

**Service**

@

```
Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/equipos")
public class ServicieAtleta {

    @Autowired
    private DaoAtletaI iAtleta;

    @RequestMapping(value="/insert")
    public @ResponseBody Atleta insertrAtleta (@RequestParam(value="skill", required= true ) ??? ????,
                                                @RequestParam(value="result", required= true ) ??? ???

                                            )
    {


        Atleta atl = iAtleta.saveAndFlush(new Atleta(???? , ????);
        return atl;



    }


}
```

How can I write the params that make reference to objects?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: why do you need custom method for that, JpaRepository already has method for persisting entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only run [update and delete modifying queries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries):

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("delete from User u where u.active = false")
void deleteInactiveUsers();
```

That's because Hibernate only supports these DML style batch operations.

For inserts you have to use EntityManager persist and merge and a custom Repository method.

You need to use the entity ids when referencing an entity. The REST service must take the skillId as a parameter to create an Atelta entity.

```
Skill skill = iAtleta.findOne(skillId);
Atleta atl = iAtleta.saveAndFlush(new Atleta(skill , result);
```

Comment: Vlad Mihalcea thanks for answer, you are right! please check the edit